# Convert Numbers (year/week eg. 201501)) to their next greater number - in R

Tags: r, numeric

I have a data where one column is year and the week .

```
Data
201501

201501

201502

201503
201552
......
201601

201602...........
201652

201701
```

Here 201501 refers to first week of 2015 and 201552 refers to the last week of the 2015.. so on ....What I want to covert these year/week combination to there next year week combination.. so 201501 becomes 201502 and 201552 becomes 201601 Example:

```
Original Data    Converted Data

201501             201502

201501             201502

201502             201503

201503             201504.......

201552             201601

201601             201602....

201652             201701

201701             201702
```

I can get that by adding 1 but it will not work once it is changing to 2015 to 2016...
Anyway to do this ?

Comment: It seems that you're using your list to work out the next greater number, right? How can you have a converted number for the last element in that list? Where did `201702` come from?

Comment: Are you saying you want it to go to the next greatest number that is present in your data or that you want it to treat your number as 'yyyymm' and add a month?  There are inconsistencies in both interpretations for your sample data so providing clarification would be useful.

Comment: Hello Dason, Thank you very much for pointing that out. I agree that my interpretations were not clear. I have made some changes does it make sense now ?

Answer (score 3):

```
df = read.table(text = "
Data
201501
201501
201502
201503
201601
201602
201701
", header=T)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  distinct() %>%                          # keep unique values
  mutate(ConvertedData = lead(Data)) %>%  # add lead values (i.e. next greater value) and create a look up table
  right_join(df, by="Data")               # right join your original data

#     Data ConvertedData
# 1 201501        201502
# 2 201501        201502
# 3 201502        201503
# 4 201503        201601
# 5 201601        201602
# 6 201602        201701
# 7 201701            NA
```

This approach assumes that your original dataset has the correct order of values.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Data` in data frame `df` is in ascending order, here's an approach that uses `unique` and `match`. First, here's the data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(Data = c(201501,201501,201502,201503,201601,201602,201701))

#     Data
# 1 201501
# 2 201501
# 3 201502
# 4 201503
# 5 201601
# 6 201602
# 7 201701
```

Next, I do the conversion and bind it to the original data frame.

```
cbind(df, Converted = with(df, unique(Data)[match(Data, unique(Data))+1]))

#     Data Converted
# 1 201501    201502
# 2 201501    201502
# 3 201502    201503
# 4 201503    201601
# 5 201601    201602
# 6 201602    201701
# 7 201701        NA
```

This works by finding all the unique values in the column. Then, it matches each element in the column to these unique values. Finally, it adds one so that it references the next largest unique value.